# TextView disappears off screen on rotate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, orientation

I've got a chain of three text views next to one another so that in landscape mode they all align perfectly, however when I rotate to portrait mode they still try to align horizontal although I would like them to align one below another so that they fit on screen. I've tried getting the screen orientation and setting the LinearLayout that contains the 3 text views orientation on screen orientation change but to no avail. Any pointers?

Comment: LinearLayout can be vertical or horizontal, which one are you using?

Comment: That is the thing, I've had it as horizontal as a default because I've been forcing the xml layout to landscape however I want it to be autorotable now so that when the xml is viewed in portrait then the linearlayout should be vertical and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different layout for different orientations. Assuming you have `main.xml`. Just place it under two folders `layout` and `layout-land`, but with one difference: in first one make your `LinearLayout` vertical, in second one - horizontal. Your app will be automatically switch them when orientation change event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different layout for portrait mode.

`res/layout-land/yourLayout.xml` will be used for landscape mode, `res/layout/yourLayout.xml` for the portrait, name the files and the views inside the same and the right layout will be inflated on orientation change.